# Elm: Ports not working in nested modules

Tags: javascript, nested, elm, ports

I'm trying to get ports working in a nested module, by adapting a working example to be nested. In this case Save2.elm calls fileSelected, a JavaScript function. 
However, this does not work.

Debugging shows that the message "Json Selected" is fired. Unfortunately, the JavaScript function never gets called.
The defined port in Ports.elm:

```
port fileSelected : String -> Cmd msg
```

Relevant part of Save2.elm, the "Json Selected" part is fired:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        JsonSelected inputBoxId ->
            ( model
            , fileSelected inputBoxId
            )
```

The relevant JavaScript part:

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = Elm.Main.fullscreen();
    // This log is shown from start-up
    console.log("Upload.html console.log is shown")
    app.ports.fileSelected.subscribe(function (id) {
      // This log is never shown
      console.log("fileSelected is executed")
```

A link to the repo:
https://github.com/gitLabor8/Elm-Ports-not-working-in-nested-modules

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your repo, the `Cmd` from `Save2.update` is just ignored in `Main.update`.

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Save2 saveMsg ->
            ( { model | save2 = Tuple.first (Save2.update saveMsg model.save2) }
            , Cmd.none
            )
```

You need to return it from `Main.update` so that Elm runtime can handle the `Cmd`.

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Save2 saveMsg ->
            let
                ( save2Model, save2Cmd )
                    = Save2.update saveMsg model.save2
            in
                ( { model | save2 = save2Model }
                , save2Cmd
                )
```

In Elm, calling `port` functions don't trigger anything. They just return `Cmd`s that have to be handled by Elm runtime.